# How to Insert data from login form into database table

Tags: blackberry

I am new to blackberry, i am doing application in eclipse,i got an situation, how to insert values into the database when entering the data in the login form which contain 2 fields username and password in blackberry applications, please provide solution.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite difficult to understand what are you asking here.

Do you want to add login form data to a local (mobile) database? Or you want to add it to a centralized (to all applications) server?

In the former case, you need to use BlackBerry APIs to create and populate databases using Persistent Object Store (which is always available for BlackBerry Apps) or use any other database you can separately install in BlackBerry. Also consider using [SQLite](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/8682/SQLite_overview_701956_11.jsp) (integrated with BlackBerry OS 5 or superior).

In the latter case, you need to send login data through HTTP (or any other TCP based protocol) and once data is on you application server, you can insert it on any database it supports: MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, SQLServer, Sybase, you name it.

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/8673/JDE_5.0_SQLiteGuide.pdf

DataStorage concept comes here.For this first of all learn how data can be inserted to a database table..The above link is a guide which helps you to learn everything about how table can be created,stored retrieved.

Store the data you entered in a variable  viz.username,password using persistent storage..
Use these variable names in the Insertion syntax..